# How can I stop a infinitie loop in my code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infinite-loop

So I'm new to this and Im trying to create a sliding puzzle in react, so far I have an array which I tried to shuffle thats, where the loop is and Ive used lodash to split the array into four.
But I need to stop that loop that is running on newArr, anyone that can help me understand how to do that?

When I update the page the newArr it's run mulitple times and as well when I shuffle the board of tiles with the shuffle btn, how can I write so that the getShuffledArr only runs once when update or shuffle?

```js
const sortedArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];


const getShuffledArr = () => {
  const newArr = sortedArray.slice();
  for (let i = newArr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [newArr[i], newArr[rand]] = [newArr[rand], newArr[i]];
    console.log("newArr", newArr);
  }
  let newPuzzle = newArr
  return newPuzzle
};

const newPuzzle = getShuffledArr()

// this gives four arrays of the shuffled one
const newPuzzleArr = () => {
  let puzzleArr = _.chunk(newPuzzle, 4)
  console.log("getNewArray", puzzleArr);
  return puzzleArr
}
newPuzzleArr()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why not try either stepping through the code, or putting some log statements in so you can get a better idea of what the code is doing as it runs?

Comment: There's no infinite loop. Your code runs and terminates just fine. If you are experiencing long wait times then its probably due to the size of the input data.

Comment: Can you edit this question and add a few sentences explaining what you mean about your comment in the code that reads: _this gives an infinity loop, needs to get a condition to run only when updates?_  What do you mean by _updates_?

Comment: I will do that @DaveNewton, thanks!

Comment: I've tried to explain more @Wyck, thanks for looking!

Comment: @AnnaAlmestal, you're asking how to avoid calling `getShuffledArr` multiple times, but I see it's only called once in the code snipped you provided.  So you haven't shown us the code that needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already using lodash then you can use the `_.shuffle(arr)` method.
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#shuffle

Comment: @AnnaAlmestal if it works, accept this as the answer :)